# How to read row by row data from table like SQLReader using LINQ

Tags: linq-to-sql

May anybody tell me how to replace this code using Linq ?

using using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;

```
Public IDataReader GetRowByRowData()
{
 Database Db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
 string sqlString = "SELECT *  FROM TableTest";
 DbCommand DbCmd = PpwDb.GetSqlStringCommand(sqlString);
 Db .ExecuteReader(DbCmd);
}
```

Please help to get row by row data from table TableTest using Linq

Answer (score 1):

you can do that like this:

```
   var myQyery=from a in dataContext.Mytable
           select a;

  foreach(var item in myQuery)
{
    //what you like
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var records = (from p in context.TableTest
               select p).ToList();

foreach(var record in records) {
  // loop through each record here
}
```

`ToList` method will query the database and get the result set.

Comment: Thanks Nima And Sridhar.SqlReader Reads row by row .It holds only one row at a time when we read from it.But the anonymous variable holds all records.Please suggest replacement of sqlReader using Linq to Sql ?

Comment: @Nima:Thanks Nima And Sridhar.SqlReader Reads row by row .It holds only one row at a time when we read from it.But the anonymous variable holds all records.Please suggest replacement of sqlReader using Linq to Sql ?

Answer (score 0):

I load the primary key from my table into a list. Depending on the size of the data set and the primary key, loading into a list does not take too long. After loading the keys, use FirstOrDefault() with a where clause like so:

```
var keys = Db.TableTest.Select(x => x.primaryKey).ToList();

foreach (var k in keys)
{
    var record = (from i in Db.TableTest
             where i.primaryKey == k
             select new
             {
              //Select only the columns you need to conserve memory
                 col1 = i.col1,
                 col2 = i.col2
             }).FirstOrDefault();

    //Process the record
}
```